# Flexslider caption toggle won't stay hidden

Tags: jquery, plugins, flexslider, caption

I have a question about toggling a caption on and off for Flexslider slides.

The caption starts off hidden, and I have a "Description" button that can be clicked to toggle the caption on and off.

The caption hiding works fine, however, once the caption is toggled on it doesn't go away when "Description" is clicked again and remains on the subsequent slides. It can be toggled off on the current slide, but will reappear on the next.

I tried looking everywhere for a solution to this but I'm at a loss!

My Jquery:

```
$(".slideinfo").hide();

$(".description").click(function(){
    $(".slideinfo").fadeToggle(1000);   
});

$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    keyboard: true,
    animation: "fade",
    slideshow: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 3000,
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    touch: true,
    video: false,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true,
    controlsContainer: ".pager",  
});
```

Here is an example of the problem happening: [link](http://hellothisis.cc/streusel/stitched.html)